# Debezium CDC on PostgreSQL and transactions

Tags: postgresql, transactions, cdc, debezium

I'd like to use Debezium for Change Data Capture(CDC) on PostgreSQL database. Right now I don't fully understand how to deal with transactions in Debezium.

Let's consider the following example - I have 2 tables in source PostgreSQL database. I'm inserting data into both of these table in scope of single database transaction. In other words I have to execute two separate `INSERT` statement. If I understand correctly in case of Debezium CDC it will result into two separate messages into two separate Kafka topics(or AWS Kinesis streams). Each of these messages will be consumed by own consumer and inserted into the target database in separate transaction. In case one of the transaction fail, the other can be successful and I'll run into the data inconsistency state in the target database.

Is there any standard  mechanisms in Debezium to handle such situation? Or for example, in order to avoid it, I have to use Kafka Streams API and join these two topics into a single one(on transactionId) before updating the target db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You describe the default behaviour correctly.

If you'd like to write multiple records into a sink database using one transaction, you'll likely have to use a bespoke consumer application which buffers the events originating from one transaction internally and writes them out to the sink database at once in a single transaction. Simply pulling events together on one topic won't help you, as a generic sink connector still wouldn't know about the source transactional boundaries.

You can use Debezium's [transaction metadata](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-transaction-metadata) topic for that. It provides all the info such consumer app would need for implementing such buffering logic. Unfortunately, we don't have a comprehensive demo for this yet, but I hope we'll get to blog about this very soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please let me summarize my understanding of what you have said. I need to implement bespoke applcation that will listent all of the Kafka topics for the tables that participate in my business transactions and collect all of the events somewhere on my side in some buffer(in memory or in database). Also I need to listen events in the Debezium's transaction metadata topic and thus I'll know each source transaction boundaries(events number, etc).

Comment: Once I understand that I have locally collected all of the events for the specific transaction, I'll replicate these changes to my sink database in a scope of single transaction. And will repeat this step for each transaction I have in Debezium's transaction metadata topic. Am I correct?

Comment: And if so, how about initial snapshot of the existing data in the source database that Debezium will try lo load after the very first execution? Will Debezium follow such scenario on the existing data in the source database?

Comment: You're right with your first two comments. Re snapshots, that TX currently is not represented on the TX metadata topic (we've planned to add that). There's a marker in the `source` block of change events though which tells you if this is the last snapshot event. That way, you should be able to await all snapshot events, but you might end up with a large transaction when writing out the events all at once.

Comment: I apologize to bother you with an additional question on this topic — in order to use Debezium I'm going to upgrade old existing PostgreSQL 9.2 database to some new version which supports Write-Ahead Log(WAL). After upgrade, will Debezium be able to capture initial snapshot of the existing data from this database? I'm asking because initial(existing data) was formed on old database without WAL.

Comment: Yes, the snapshot is read via JDBC, i.e. the WAL format doesn't make any difference for that. You could even take a snapshot (only) with PG 9.2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please also take a look into the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418001/debezium-embedded-engine-with-aws-kinesis-postgresql-snapshot-load-and-transac

Comment: Just wondering, did the blog that you mentioned ever get published? :)